# switch from 3 column to 2 column in boostrap layout, when middle column is larger than the others

Tags: html, css

I have the following situation using boostrap layout:

3 column layout in lg and md form factor.

```
  *---*-----*---*
  | A |     | C |
  *---|  B  |---*
      |     |   
      *-----*
```

When I switch to sm form factor I desire that my columns wrap as follow:

```
    *---*-----*
    | A |     |
    *---*  B  |
    | C |     |
    *---*-----*
```

But it leaves me with a layout like:

```
   *---*-----*
   | A |     |
   *---|  B  |
       |     |
   *---*-----*
   | C |
   *---*
```

Any idea how to get the desired behavior?

here my html code :

```
<div class="row">
   <div class=" col-num-1 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-3">1</div>
   <div class="col-num-2 col-sm-9 col-md-8 col-lg-6">2</div>
   <div class="col-num-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-3">3</div>
</div>
```

here my css code:

```
.col-num-1 {
    background-color: #7CBEB1;
    height: 100px;
}

.col-num-2 {
    background-color: #EA865A;
    height: 300px;
 }

.col-num-3 {
    background-color: #38455B;
    height: 100px;
 }
```

se the fiddle for further clarification
   http://jsfiddle.net/ujrwyrbr/15/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `float: right;` to the middle column when smaller than 992px but larger than 768px.

```
@media (max-width: 992px) and (min-width: 768px) {
   .col-num-2 {
       float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wusvgvd5/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot  @Roope for the quick response. That solve the problem.